# index out of range in same making loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, range

I'm trying to understand my little exercise. I tested with the same input but in two different coding ways. One of them ran well, the other one got string index out of range.Input: abBAcC
I got this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python_courses\leetcode_make_string_great\make_string_great.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(checkObj.makeGood(stringCheck))
  File "d:\python_courses\leetcode_make_string_great\make_string_great.py", line 6, in makeGood
    if ord(s[index]) == ord(s[index + 1]) + 32 or ord(s[index]) == ord(s[index + 1]) - 32:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This one is geting an error:

```
class Solution:
    def makeGood(self, s: str) -> str:
        while len(s) > 1:
            find = False
            for index in range(len(s) - 1):
                if ord(s[index]) == ord(s[index + 1]) + 32 or ord(s[index]) == ord(s[index + 1]) - 32:
                    s = s.replace(s[index: index + 2], '')
                    find = True
            
            if not find:
                break

        return s
```

So I found another way. It runs well but I've not seen any difference between them.

```
class Solution:
    def makeGood(self, s: str) -> str:
        # if s has less than 2 characters, we just return itself.
        while len(s) > 1:
            # 'find' records if we find any pair to remove.
            find = False
            # Check every two adjacent characters, curr_char and next_char.
            for i in range(len(s) - 1):
                curr_char, next_char = s[i], s[i + 1]
                # If they make a pair, remove them from 's' and let 'find = True'.
                if abs(ord(curr_char) - ord(next_char)) == 32:
                    s = s[:i] + s[i + 2:]
                    find = True
                    break
            # If we cannot find any pair to remove, break the loop. 
            if not find:
                break
        return s
```

Is there anyone can point why I get this error? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to imagine how your first code works: in your example at each iteration `index` will take values from `0` to `len(s)-1`, i.e. `5`.

But when `index` is `1` you find 'bB' and `s` becomes 'aAcC'. When `index` is `2` you find 'cC' and `s` is now only 'aA'. Now `index` becomes `3` and you get the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought the range would change when the string changed.